# Understanding D3 Force-Layout: Why previous node values x,y NOT EQUAL px,py after 1 timestep?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm running through [Stephen A. Thomas's D3 Force Layout tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/26648f33f3bc9725604a) and generally playing around with each one as I go, making modifications, and trying to get a deeper understanding of the force layout. On example 3, I'm noticing something that just seems a little weird and hoping someone can explain why this is the case.

I made modifications ***(see snippit below)*** that draw the path nodes take as they go from their initial to final positions by drawing a line from `px` to `x` during each tick.

**For some reason, the actual position of a node last tick does not equal listed previous (px,py) position during the current tick; alternatively, `node.x(t), node.y(t)` does not equal `node.px(t+1), node.py(t+1)`...**

First step:
[image]

Second step:
[image]

Gaps in path show errors:

[image]

I'm sure in virtually every use case out there this doesn't really matter, but in the spirit of understanding how the force layout works can someone explain what's going on here? Is it something specific to the way I (or the tutorial) is stepping through ticks and, if so, why?

```js
// Define the dimensions of the visualization. We're using
// a size that's convenient for displaying the graphic on
// http://jsDataV.is

var width = 1600,
    height = 900;
  
// Before we do anything else, let's define the data for the visualization.

var graph = {
    "nodes": [  { "x": 208.992345, "y": 273.053211 },
                { "x": 595.98896,  "y":  56.377057 },
                { "x": 319.568434, "y": 278.523637 },
                { "x": 214.494264, "y": 214.893585 },
                { "x": 482.664139, "y": 340.386773 },
                { "x":  84.078465, "y": 192.021902 },
                { "x": 196.952261, "y": 370.798667 },
                { "x": 107.358165, "y": 435.15643  },
                { "x": 401.168523, "y": 443.407779 },
                { "x": 508.368779, "y": 386.665811 },
                { "x": 355.93773,  "y": 460.158711 },
                { "x": 283.630624, "y":  87.898162 },
                { "x": 194.771218, "y": 436.366028 },
                { "x": 477.520013, "y": 337.547331 },
                { "x": 572.98129,  "y": 453.668459 },
                { "x": 106.717817, "y": 235.990363 },
                { "x": 265.064649, "y": 396.904945 },
                { "x": 452.719997, "y": 137.886092 }
            ],
    "links": [  { "target": 11, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  3, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 10, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 16, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  1, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  3, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  9, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  5, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 11, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 16, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  3, "source":  1 },
                { "target":  9, "source":  1 },
                { "target": 12, "source":  1 },
                { "target":  4, "source":  2 },
                { "target":  6, "source":  2 },
                { "target":  8, "source":  2 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  2 },
                { "target": 10, "source":  3 },
                { "target": 16, "source":  3 },
                { "target":  9, "source":  3 },
                { "target":  7, "source":  3 },
                { "target": 11, "source":  5 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  5 },
                { "target": 12, "source":  5 },
                { "target":  8, "source":  6 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  6 },
                { "target": 10, "source":  7 },
                { "target": 11, "source":  7 },
                { "target": 17, "source":  8 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  8 },
                { "target": 11, "source": 10 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 10 },
                { "target": 13, "source": 11 },
                { "target": 14, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 14, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 14, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 15, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 15, "source": 14 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 14 },
                { "target": 15, "source": 14 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 15 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 15 },
                { "target": 17, "source": 16 }
            ]
    };

// Here's were the code begins. We start off by creating an SVG
// container to hold the visualization. We only need to specify
// the dimensions for this container.

var svg = d3.select('div').append('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
    .attr("width", "100%")

// Extract the nodes and links from the data.
var nodes = graph.nodes,
    links = graph.links;


var c = d3.scale.category20();
  
// Now we create a force layout object and define its properties.
// Those include the dimensions of the visualization and the arrays
// of nodes and links.

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links);

// There's one more property of the layout we need to define,
// its `linkDistance`. That's generally a configurable value and,
// for a simple example, we'd normally leave it at its default.
// Unfortunately, the default value results in a visualization
// that's not especially clear. This parameter defines the
// distance (normally in pixels) that we'd like to have between
// nodes that are connected. (It is, thus, the length we'd
// like our links to have.)

force.linkDistance(width/4);

// Next we'll add the nodes and links to the visualization.
// Note that we're just sticking them into the SVG container
// at this point. We start with the links. The order here is
// important because we want the nodes to appear "on top of"
// the links. SVG doesn't really have a convenient equivalent
// to HTML's `z-index`; instead it relies on the order of the
// elements in the markup. By adding the nodes _after_ the
// links we ensure that nodes appear on top of links.

// Links are pretty simple. They're just SVG lines. We're going
// to position the lines according to the centers of their
// source and target nodes. You'll note that the `source`
// and `target` properties are indices into the `nodes`
// array. That's how our JSON is structured and that's how
// D3's force layout expects its inputs. As soon as the layout
// begins executing, however, it's going to replace those
// properties with references to the actual node objects
// instead of indices.

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return nodes[d.source].x; })
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return nodes[d.source].y; })
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return nodes[d.target].x; })
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return nodes[d.target].y; });

// Now it's the nodes turn. Each node is drawn as a circle and
// given a radius and initial position within the SVG container.
// As is normal with SVG circles, the position is specified by
// the `cx` and `cy` attributes, which define the center of the
// circle. We actually don't have to position the nodes to start
// off, as the force layout is going to immediately move them.
// But this makes it a little easier to see what's going on
// before we start the layout executing.

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', width/100)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("fill", function(d,i){ return c(i); });
 
var roundTo = 1;
 
var loci = svg.selectAll('.nodeLoci')
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append('text')
  .attr('class','nodeLoci')
  .text(function(d){ return 'x: '+ d3.round(d.x,roundTo) +', y: ' + d3.round(d.y,roundTo) + '; px: '+ d3.round(d.px,roundTo) + ', py: '+ d3.round(d.py,roundTo); })
  .attr('x', width-400)
  .attr('y', function(d,i) { return 50+i*30; });
  
var trail = svg.selectAll('.trail')
  .data(nodes)
  
trail.enter().append('circle')
  .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
  .attr("r", width/200)
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
  .attr("stroke", function(d,i){ return c(i); })
  .attr("stroke-width", 2);

// Before we get into the force layout operation itself,
// we define a variable that indicates whether or not
// we're animating the operation. Initially it's false.

var animating = false;

// We'll also define a variable that specifies the duration
// of each animation step (in milliseconds).

var animationStep = 200;

// Next we define a function that executes at each
// iteration of the force layout.

force.on('tick', function() {
 
    // When this function executes, the force layout
    // calculations have been updated. The layout will
    // have set various properties in our nodes and
    // links objects that we can use to position them
    // within the SVG container.

    // First let's reposition the nodes. As the force
    // layout runs it updates the `x` and `y` properties
    // that define where the node should be centered.
    // To move the node, we set the appropriate SVG
    // attributes to their new values.

    // Because we want to emphasize how the nodes and
    // links move, we use a transition to move them to
    // their positions instead of simply setting the
    // values abruptly.
 
  trail.enter().append('line')
    .attr('class','trail')
    .attr("x1", function(d){ return d.px; })
    .attr("y1", function(d){ return d.py; })
    .attr("x2", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d){ return d.y; })
    .attr("stroke", function(d,i){ return c(i); });
    
  trail.enter().append('circle')
  .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
  .attr("r", width/500)
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
  .attr("stroke", function(d,i){ return c(i); })
  .attr("stroke-width", 1);
    
    node.transition().ease('linear').duration(animationStep)
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
  
  loci.text(function(d){ return 'x: '+ d3.round(d.x,roundTo) +', y: ' + d3.round(d.y,roundTo) + '; px: '+ d3.round(d.px,roundTo) + ', py: '+ d3.round(d.py,roundTo); })
    
    // We also need to update positions of the links.
    // For those elements, the force layout sets the
    // `source` and `target` properties, specifying
    // `x` and `y` values in each case.

    // Here's where you can see how the force layout has
    // changed the `source` and `target` properties of
    // the links. Now that the layout has executed at least
    // one iteration, the indices have been replaced by
    // references to the node objects.

    link.transition().ease('linear').duration(animationStep)
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    // We only show one tick at a time, so stop the layout
    // for now.

    force.stop();

    // If we're animating the layout, continue after
    // a delay to allow the animation to take effect.

    if (animating) {
        setTimeout(
            function() { force.start(); },
            animationStep
        );
    }

});

// Now let's take care of the user interaction controls.
// We'll add functions to respond to clicks on the individual
// buttons.

// When the user clicks on the "Advance" button, we
// start the force layout (The tick handler will stop
// the layout after one iteration.)

d3.select('#advance').on('click', force.start);

// When the user clicks on the "Play" button, we're
// going to run the force layout until it concludes.

d3.select('#slow').on('click', function() {

    // Since the buttons don't have any effect any more,
    // disable them.

    d3.selectAll('button').attr('disabled','disabled');

    // Indicate that the animation is in progress.

    animating = true;

    // Get the animation rolling

    force.start();

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 1600px
}

svg {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
}
 
.node {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

.nodeLoci {
    font-size: 1.5em;    
}

.link {
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
}
button#slow {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <button id='advance' title='Advance Layout One Increment'>
        <i class='fa fa-step-forward'></i>
    </button>
    <button id='slow'    title='Run Layout in Slow Motion'>
        <i class='fa fa-play'></i>
    </button>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js) helps here. In particular lines 125-126:

```
o.x -= (o.px - (o.px = o.x)) * friction;
o.y -= (o.py - (o.py = o.y)) * friction;
```

The friction of the layout is taken into account as well when updating the node positions.

Comment: Thanks Lars! Your answer alone doesn't seem to answer the question fully. Even factoring in friction, it's not inherently clear to me why the (x,y) isn't the same as the (px,py) at the next timestep. However, looking at your ans and the source code you linked, I do find it interesting that (px,py) aren't updated until AFTER (x,y) are already modified by link relaxation, gravity and charge forces. Because (px,py) are updated "late", the gaps/"errors" seen are actually the pos changes caused by the forces; the lines that I'm plotting are how much nodes are "sliding" dependent on friction. Agree?

Comment: Yes, the full code is a lot more complex and a lot more things are taken into account.